# Ssh client to telnet Server JAVA

Tags: java, ssh, telnet, jsch

I have telnet server and telnet client and i am making requests and responses.

Now instead of telnet client i need to use SSH client. For the ssh client I am using Jsch. I am trying to connect my client to the telnet server but I have errors.

So my question is: Is it possible to connect SSH client to telnet server and to make requests and responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible as telnet and ssh are different protocols.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!